# ASP.Net string from server side

Tags: asp.net

I have a string in server-side. I want to bind this string to textbox's text propery or image's imageurl property.

Server-Side

```
public string image_path = "@/tool_images/10000000s0.png";
```

I tried these in Client-Side

```
 <asp:Image ID="t10000000" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%=image_path %>' />  
 <asp:TextBox ID="ASPTextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%= image_path %>' />
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="<%# image_path %>" />
```

It can't work.

for '<%= %>' output is <%= image_path %> 
for '<%# %>' output is nothing

If output is true I want to bind this ImageURL propery

Comment: <%# (Eval("put the field here you want to check against")!=null) ? Eval(image_path) : "" %>

Comment: Are those Image and TextBoxes located inside GridView or some other data control?

Comment: @Win No. Just in div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<%#  %>` is for binding data to control, so you will need to call ***DataBind*** method for each control.

```
<asp:Image ID="t10000000" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# image_path %>' />
<asp:TextBox ID="ASPTextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# image_path %>' />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="<%# image_path %>" />

// Code Behind
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        t10000000.DataBind();
        ASPTextBox1.DataBind();
        TextBox1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

***FYI:*** in ASP.Net Web Form, we don't normally use that approach to bind data to control, unless those controls are in data control like GridView, ListView or Repeater. In other words, we just assign value in Code Behind like `t10000000.ImageUrl = image_path;`

Comment: Thanks it works. But my main purpose is change image URL dynamically according to <img> id.

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operator.
Let me know if it works for you.

booleanExpression ? trueValue : falseValue